# Insert audio at random intervals with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I see a very good example of adding a logo to a ramdom position on the image. I am wondering if I can do that with audio. I tried "between" and "atrim". but no examples are available
I want to add the audio so it shuffle around 3 to 9 minutes. Is it available.

```
I can use
```

if (eq (mod (t , 30) , 0) , rand (0 , (W-tw)) , x): 
y = if (eq (mod (t , 30) , 0) , rand (0 , (H-th)) , y) "for my case?

Comment: What's your filterchain?

Comment: I try it with sound. But it doesn't seem to be working. I don't know where was wrong.

Comment: Show your command and the complete log.